# Maximum stack depth exceeded in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, collections

i have a ressource collection :

```
class OverviewResource extends JsonResource
{
    
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email, 
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'friends' => OverviewResource::collection(User::getFriends()),
        ];
    }
}
```

i have an error in this line

```
'friends' => OverviewResource::collection(User::getFriends()),
```

when calling this function from User model

```
    public static function getFriends(){
         return User::where
            //query code here
        })->get();
    }
```

i got this error

> Maximum stack depth exceeded

Comment: i guess it's because of the recursive call of OverViewRessource  but how can replace it ?

Comment: Why not define a `friends` relationship on User, then simply modify your code to `'friends' => $this->friends`? You're correct that the recursive call to itself is causing this issue 

Comment: the relationship already exists, it returns the friend's id's then I search for users with these id's and return them using this collection resource

Comment: Then it would be `'friends' => $this->getFriends()`. Either way, you'll have to rethink your approach here  Sidenote, a Relationship shouldn't just return the ids, but rather the Models fetched from the DB. You can then call `$this->friends->pluck('id')` to get those if you need em.

Comment: well that how it was it's returning User objects but I want User objects to be passed to the OverViewResource to fetch complementary data, you see the problem now ?

Comment: Kinda; you want to load Users and their Friends, then their Friends, and so on and so forth, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user has `n` friends then:

`OverviewResource::collection(User::getFriends())`

is going to create `n` new resources.

Each of those resources will call:

`OverviewResource::collection(User::getFriends())`

and create `n` new resources.

Each of those new resources then calls it again, and then the new ones again, ... Until you reach the maximum stack allowed.

You're going to have to rethink how you implement your recursion so that it terminates.